# Excel formula to look for X and add

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to write a formula that will look at 2 separate boxes for an X and if it sees an X in the box then add 2 separate boxes together and if it doesn't see an X in one of the two boxes then it will just show what is in one of the boxes.

I.E.:  if A1 and B1 have an X then add A2 to B2. If A1 does not have an X then just show what is in B2.

Comment: =if((A1,b1)="X",(A2+b2),b2)

Comment: @RickD Did you try my answer?

Comment: Not yet. I will try in a bit. I haven't had time.

Comment: A2 and b2 will be numbers. So you find find X in A2 or B2.

Comment: @RickD you need to substitute the number you want to look for for X in my formulas below (you can drop the quotes too)

Comment: I want TJ make sure, does your formula reflect looking for X in A1 or B1?it seems  o me it is looking for X in A2 and B2.

Comment: To not TJ.     Autocorrect.

Answer (score 2):

So you can't find X in A2 or B2, then show B2, else show their sum:

```
=IF(OR(IFERROR(FIND("X", A2),0)=0, IFERROR(FIND("X", B2),0)=0),B2,A2+B2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=B2+IF(COUNTIF(A1:B1,"X")=2,A2)
```